# Reverse DIrection Linear Gradient

Tags: android, gradient, reverse, linear-gradients

I have this code:

```
LinearGradient backlg = new LinearGradient(0, 0, 10, 10,
            new int[]{Color.BLACK, Color.BLACK, Color.BLUE, Color.BLUE},
            new float[]{0,0.5f,.55f,1}, Shader.TileMode.REPEAT);
```

Which creates diagonal bands alternating between blue and black.  They go from Bottom left to top right so here is my question, what do I change to make it go from top left to bottom right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you mean:

```
LinearGradient backlg = new LinearGradient(0, 10, 10, 0,
        new int[]{Color.BLACK, Color.BLACK, Color.BLUE, Color.BLUE},
        new float[]{0,0.5f,.55f,1}, Shader.TileMode.REPEAT);
```

Answer (score 1):

Checkout the [documentation][1] for that constructor. The first 4 parameters are the x,y coordinates for the start and end of the gradient line.

So if 0,0 is bottom left and 10,10 is top right, try going from 0,10 to 10,0.

[1]: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/LinearGradient.html#LinearGradient(float, float, float, float, int[], float[], android.graphics.Shader.TileMode)